# SELECT * FROM tbl name WHERE name LIKE 'ask'

Tags: php, mysql

Hy, i have a sql tabl name `kill`, with fields like

- `ID`
- `name`
- `lname`.

There are several names are same, like `ali`, `kiran` etc, i want to show all the people with the name ali, so i tried this

```
SELECT * FROM ask WHERE name LIKE 'ali'
```

but it shows only the last added ali, please will you tell me the right way to do this. thanks

Comment: use  `LIKE '%ali%'` or `='ali'`. Also Show your php code

Answer (score 3):

IF you are trying to find all values containing `ali` for e.g.

- Bali
- Alison

etc...

What you need to do is run a wildcard search query, so try this:

```
SELECT * FROM ask WHERE name LIKE '%ali%'
```

This will find all values where name contains part of `ali` in it.

If you want to find all names ending in `ali`, you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM ask WHERE name LIKE '%ali'
```

If you want to find all names starting with `ali`, you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM ask WHERE name LIKE 'ali%'
```

etc...

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use REGEXP, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM ask WHERE name REGEXP 'ali';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be as below:-

```
SELECT * FROM ask WHERE name LIKE '%ali%'
```

Check this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html) for detailed info.

Answer (score 1):

The Syntax for query in your case is
**SQL LIKE Syntax**

> `SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE pattern;`

You should use query below to selects all names **starting with the letter "ali"**:

```
SELECT * FROM ask WHERE name LIKE 'ali%';
```

You should use query below to selects all names **ending with the letter "ali"**:

```
SELECT * FROM ask WHERE name LIKE '%ali';
```

You should use query below to selects all names **containing  the letter "ali"**:

```
SELECT * FROM ask WHERE name LIKE '%ali%';
```

---

**Refer** This [link for tutorials on Like.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM ask WHERE name LIKE '%ali%';
```

Comment: Do not only add the query. Explain what you have changed